# User is able to see a inaccessible link

Tags: 7, routes

I had created menu link using hook_menu

```
  $items['admin/config/xyz'] = array(
    'title' => 'xyz Webservice Settings',
    'description' => 'Configures the xyz Settings',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('xyz_services_admin_settings'),
    'access callback' => 'user_access',
    'access arguments' => array('administer xyz configuration'),
  );
```

I've added this link to the main menu and I am rendering main menu block in the sidebar.

Now, The user goes to home page and that user doesn't have access to the above link but still, he can see the link in the sidebar, Why?

I debugged a little bit and found that drupal is taking parent path 'admin/config' and the user have access to this link maybe that's why he can see the link but why he is taking the parent link??